# Maytag Dryer wiring issue

Tags: wiring, dryer

I have a Maytag Dryer model number LDE8420ACW that was give to me. The yellow, blue, purple and 2 white wires that connect to the power terminal block that the power supply cord hooks to are not connected to the terminal.  I would like to know what wires hook together or  what they hook to. It is a 3 (prong) wire terminal block. The 5 wires mentioned have numbers on them if it is of any help the 3 wires coming from the control panel are labeled white-22 , purple-23 , yellow-34 and the 2 wires coming from below are labeled blue-28 and white-29.

Comment: Did the dryer come with a wiring diagram?

Comment: No it didn't come with any schematics

Comment: Please re-read that post and revise, adding periods to make sentences. Some of it is difficult to decipher.

Comment: There is usually a schematic inside the control panel or inside a removable panel in the back.

Comment: I have looked inside the control panel and the body of the dryer there are no schematics.

Comment: Problem solved the Blue wire stands alone the two White go together and the Yellow and Purple go together had to do a lot of research to figure it out . This dryer is one of Maytag's most reliable machines.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: The blue wire connects to the top post of the terminal block the two White wires to the middle,  the yellow and purple to the bottom post.